# How to create a Trigram index in Django 3 with multiple columns

Tags: python, django, postgresql, full-text-search, trigram

I've implemented Trigram Similarity search with annotate which gives me exactly what I want in terms of results; but I have 220,000 records in my database and the search takes 5+ seconds per query which is too long.

The search is with 3 columns and one of those invokes a join. How do I add an index or the equivalent SearchVectorField but for Trigram to speed up my query?

See current code below:

```
trig_vector = (
    TrigramSimilarity("make__name", text)
    + TrigramSimilarity("model", text)
    + TrigramSimilarity("specification", text)
)

query_set = (
    cls.objects.annotate(similarity=trig_vector)
    .filter(similarity__gt=0.5)
    .order_by("-similarity")
)
```

I have tried making my own index from various posts but I'm not too familiar with index's and each one I've implemented hasn't has an effect on the query time.

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538419/poor-performance-when-trigram-similarity-and-full-text-search-were-combined-with/56547280#56547280) helping?